# Zend error: The apc extension must be loaded for using this backend

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, apc, zend-cache

Hi I am getting the above error setting up my Zend application on a public hosted server.  I have another application on the same sever which works ok so I assume APC is obviously loaded.  How can I diagnose this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are you using the APC Zend_Cache backend. To use this, you need the APC extension installed.

To check if it is loaded, just paste the following into a php file and then view it in a browser:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Search for the block that says something like "This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies"

If you see APC in there, then it's loaded.

Comment: Thanks, APC is not loaded and I am pursing it.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Check for "apc" extension.